# How to Handle Android ListView Subitems/childrens Click Events with SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have been developing an android application and i am stuck in the middle.

The problem is i am using `SimpleAdapter` to do the adapter stuff and show items in the `Listview` and as far as i know i cannot override the `getView()` method of `SimpleAdapter` class to bound click listeners to the items.

There is other way too to handle click events of sub items like using XML, you write the method name in the XML like `android:clickable="true" android:onClick="clicklistenr"`, using this i can get the item but my problem is if i use this method then i cannot get the position of the adapter which i need to get adapter item values and handle other tasks. So i am stuck here any help would be appreciable. thanks.

For example i have a ListView which contains one image, TextView, like Button, share Button in each of its items. And there is no way i can find that either its image or button clicked using setOnItemClickListener. So i need a way to handle click events of these sub items of a ListView, i am using SimpleAdapter.

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me. Are you trying to achieve simple onItemClick? In this case you can just use setOnItemClickListener and you'll then handle item clicks.

Comment: take look on this tutorial 
http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/

Comment: Yes i can do that but in that case i get the listView Item, not the subItems, list for example i have a listView which contains one image, like button share button in each of its items. and there is no way i can find that either its image or button clicked using setOnItemClickListener. 
So i need a way to handle click events of these sub items of a ListView, i am using SimpleAdapter.

Comment: @mohammedmomn it not show how to handle clicks events of the image or textview of the listview items and i need that. thanks.